# Is the function $f(x=\sum a_n/2^n)=\sum na_n/2^n$ continuous and nowhere differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n/2^n$ be the binary expansion of a real number in $[0,1]$. Assume that infinitely many of the $a_n$ are $0$ so that the expansion is unique.

Define $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n/2^n$.

Is $f$ continuous?

Is $f$ nowhere differentiable?

If both answers  are positive, then it seems we find a particularly simple example of such functions, which seems to me very unlikely.

Comment: Consider a number like $x = (0.01111\ldots 1)_2 =  \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2^n}$ versus $y=(0.1)_2 = \frac{1}{2}$. What is $f(y)$ an $f(x)$ (as a function of how many $1$'s there are)?

Comment: It is not too hard to show that $f$ is continuous. The second question seems a lot more complicated. I don't know the answer.

Comment: @uniquesolution Really? How would you show this? The decimal expansion of two nearby numbers can look completely different.

Comment: @Not so different as you think. In order to be $2^{-k}$ apart they must agree at least on their first $k-1$ digits.

Comment: @uniquesolution What about $0.999\ldots9$ versus $1.000000\ldots0$  ? They have zero digits in common and are as close as you would like.

Comment: Asked and answered in [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/326298/is-the-function-fx-sum-a-n-2n-sum-na-n-2n-continuous-and-nowhere-differe).  It is not continuous.